# Flutter, stuck on log in

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to redirect to a new screen after logging in

I am writing an app and need help with changing which screen is being seen, when the google sign in button is pressed it authenticates the profile, but I have no idea how to make it go to the home page after it logs in, so it just redirects back to the log-in page and the log-in process repeats. Any way for me to fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'auth.dart';
import 'flutter_auth_buttons.dart';



class LoginScreen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  final Color backgroundColor1;
  final Color backgroundColor2;
  final Color highlightColor;
  final Color foregroundColor;
  final AssetImage logo;

  LoginScreen2({Key k, this.backgroundColor1, this.backgroundColor2, this.highlightColor, this.foregroundColor, this.logo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            decoration: new BoxDecoration(
              gradient: new LinearGradient(
                begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
                end: new Alignment(1.0, 0.0),
                // 10% of the width, so there are ten blinds.
                colors: [this.backgroundColor1, this.backgroundColor2],
                // whitish to gray
                tileMode: TileMode
                    .repeated, // repeats the gradient over the canvas
              ),
            ),
            height: MediaQuery
                .of(context)
                .size
                .height,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 150.0, bottom: 50.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: new Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          height: 128.0,
                          width: 128.0,
                          child: new CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                            foregroundColor: this.foregroundColor,
                            radius: 100.0,
                            child: new Text(
                              "",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 40.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w100,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),

                        ),
                        new Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),

                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 40.0, right: 40.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(

                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 0.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: new Row(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,

                  ),
                ),
                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 30.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new Row(

                  ),
                ),

                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 100.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      GoogleSignInButton(onPressed: () =>authService.googleSignIn (
                       )) ,
                     new Expanded(
                        child: new FlatButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          onPressed: () => {},
                          child: Text(
                            "",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: this.foregroundColor.withOpacity(0.5)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),

                new Expanded(child: Divider(),),

                new Container(
                  width: MediaQuery
                      .of(context)
                      .size
                      .width,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                      left: 40.0, right: 40.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 20.0),
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new FlatButton(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 20.0),
                          color: Colors.transparent,
                          onPressed: () => {},
                          child: Text(
                            "Don't have an account? Create One",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: this.foregroundColor.withOpacity(0.5)),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ]);
  }}




  class SubPage extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Tile'),
      ),
      body: new GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        children: new List<Widget>.generate(1000, (index) {
          return new GridTile(
            child: new Card(
                color: Colors.blue.shade200,
                child: new Center(
                  child: new Text('tile $index'),
                )
            ),
          );
        }),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add your code so the problem could be identified

Comment: Fixed, sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

I shall assume that the google sign in button is calling an async job that authenticates the user info and returns a promise that informs if its a successful login or not.

In this case, you can navigate to the home page once the response is received.

```
GoogleSignInButton(
 onPressed: () => authService.googleSignIn ().then((response){
  if(response is okay){
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
  }
 })
)
```

Comment: I keep getting "The name 'okay' isn't defined, so it can't be used in an 'is' expression."

Comment: @Xantheus25 the above example is just for your illustration. "is" and "okay" does not exist in dart. I don't know what kind of response you are expecting, whether it's a bool or a map etc, you have to set it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't know how to redirect from one screen to another in Flutter.

This will help you out: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/navigation

In your case you need to use `Navigator.pushReplacement` when your Google Sign In is completed.

```
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
```

And Google Sign In may return the `Future` using which you can perform below operation.

Here `then` is a callback to be called when Google sign in future complete.

```
authService.googleSignIn.then((someValue){
      Navigator.pushReplacement(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHomePage()));
});
```

Comment: I added it as you said, but it goes to the home page and then asks for the sign in, is there no way to ask for sign in before going to home page, or did I mess up?

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean by that